# Can I synthesize potassium hydroxide from readily available materials?

Tags: synthesis

Where I live, KOH is not readily available and is cost prohibitive to ship. A number of other materials are available, however. I have read similar questions and their answers here, but most are too general or too specific for me to understand.

I could mix NaOH and KCl, both of which are available, to yield NaCl and KOH. But I'm not sure how I would separate them, as I can't think of any readily available substance that could be used to precipitate out the Na.

Or, I could mix Ca(OH)<sub>2</sub> and K<sub>2</sub>CO<sub>3</sub>, as that would produce CaCO<sub>3</sub>(s) and KOH(aq). However... I do not have K<sub>2</sub>CO<sub>3</sub> available. I could make the K<sub>2</sub>CO<sub>3</sub> myself, by baking NaHCO<sub>3</sub> into Na<sub>2</sub>CO<sub>3</sub> and mixing it with KCl to produce NaCl and K<sub>2</sub>CO<sub>3</sub>, but then I am back at having to precipitate out Na.

I could also make the K<sub>2</sub>CO<sub>3</sub> by combining C and KNO<sub>3</sub>, but... again... I do not have KNO<sub>3</sub> available. I could make KNO<sub>3</sub> from KCl and NH<sub>4</sub>NO<sub>3</sub>, but that's not available here either.

I feel stuck. KCl, NaOH, and Ca(OH)<sub>2</sub> are all available and relatively cheap. NaHCO<sub>3</sub> and NaCl are also obviously available and cheap. What else am I missing here? What else is generally available and cheap that I could use to synthesize KOH?

Comment: It would be very difficult to separate Na+ from K+ once they are in aqueous solution, because salts of both are highly soluble. I don't see any easy way to do what you wish to do. Why do you need KOH specifically? Can't NaOH do the same job?

Comment: I am planning on making liquid soap, which requires KOH. NaOH makes solid soap. I just discovered that potassium bitartrate (cream of tartar) decomposes into potassium carbonate, though, so this may be promising. Currently researching this option.

Comment: If you cannot get K2CO3 by easier way, you can get it by extraction of wooden ash, as this was the ancient way to get potash.

Comment: @Poutnik I have read that wood ash leachate contains both potassium carbonate and potassium hydroxide. Is this a mistake? Or is there a way to limit it to only one or the other? Or to know the ratio in solution, so one could add an appropriate amount of calcium hydroxide to convert all the K2CO3 to KOH?

Comment: I would doubt there is substantial amount of hydroxide, putting aside the equilibrium due carbonate hydrolysis. The needed amount of Ca(OH)2 is to be tested to avoid presence of dissolved calcium .

Comment: Related [potassium-carbonate-vs-potassium-hydroxide-in-wood-ash](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/117173/potassium-carbonate-vs-potassium-hydroxide-in-wood-ash)

Comment: "is cost prohibitive to ship" - Are you in an embargoed country or something? I find it hard to believe that KOH is cheaper to make than to ship just about anywhere in the world.  It's one of the most heavily used industrial and commercial compounds in the world.  Have you really exhaustively searched for a supplier and come up empty?  You ask *"What else is generally available and cheap that I could use to synthesize KOH?"* - well, KOH **is** generally available and cheap, so you must be somewhere where generally available things are VERY hard to find.  So *where is that*?

Comment: Wood ashes is made of $5 - 10$% $\ce{Na2CO3}$, $5 - 10$% $\ce{K2CO3}$, $2 - 3$% $\ce{K2SO4}$, $40 - 70$% $\ce{CaCO3}$, $5 - 10$% $\ce{MgCO3}$, $2 - 5$% $\ce{Ca3(PO4)2}$, $2 - 10$% $\ce{SiO2}$$. So it is not easy to obtain KOH out of this mixture..

Comment: Anyway, you may discover a process to produce $\ce{KOH}$ in solution. But you will never be able to obtain it as a pure solid, because KOH cannot be separated from water by evaporation. At high enough temperature, $\ce{KOH}$ and water are distillating together. The only way of evaporating $\ce{KOH}$ solution is to do it in a vacuum. This is the way used in the industry to produce pellets of $\ce{KOH}$

Comment: @Maurice interesting, I found this:   The major elements of wood ash include calcium (7–33%), potassium (3–4%), magnesium (1–2%), manganese (0.3–1.3%), phosphorus (0.3–1.4%), and sodium (0.2–0.5%). Density of wood ash decreases with increasing carbon content.  https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-540-74294-4_9.pdf

Comment: Can't you use bicarbonate to precipitate Na ? Admittedly the yield may be poor when it comes to separating, but it is easier to do.

Comment: Electrolysis of potassium carbonate solution is used to produce KOH and CO2. It is for homemade degreaser made in single chamber with platinum-plated electrodes. A similar apparatus is used with NaCl and acetic acid to make hypochlorous acid. Possibly you could use cheaper graphite electrodes? Wikipedia says: Potassium carbonate can be made by burning cream of tartar (potassium bitartate), which produces "pearl ash".

Comment: In which country is it necessary to use $\ce{KOH}$ (and not the more familiar $\ce{NaOH}$) without having the possibility of buying it somewhere ? What for ?

Comment: Potassium hydroxide lye from hardwood ash. Simple procedure.

Answer (score 6):

If the **only** potassium salt you have is $\ce{KCl}$, then perhaps the only feasible way to get rid of the chlorine is electrolysis.

Using a [cation-selective membrane](https://d2zo35mdb530wx.cloudfront.net/_legacy/UCPthyssenkruppBAIS/assets.files/download_1/electrolysis_1/forum_tk_2001.pdf), electrolysis in water will produce $\ce{KOH}$ (and hydrogen, $\ce{H2}$) at the anode, and chlorine, $\ce{Cl2}$, at the cathode (along with [potassium hypochlorite, $\ce(KClO)$](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Potassium-hypochlorite)).

Though this will produce the $\ce{KOH}$, it also leaves you with hydrogen, chlorine, potassium hypochlorite and other byproducts which must be disposed **safely**. Further, the process is energy intensive. This could be done as a classroom demonstration, but commercially, you'd need to find good uses for the gases and bleach/disinfectant for any chance at economic feasibility.

If you can obtain potassium carbonate ($\ce{K2CO3}$) or "bicarbonate" (acid or hydrogen carbonate, $\ce{KHCO3}$), it can, with effort, be converted to $\ce{KOH}$ by heating. That said, [decomposition temperature is ~1200 °C](https://chemiday.com/en/reaction/3-1-0-6407), which can be achieved [in a ceramic kiln - barely](https://www.soulceramics.com/pages/guide-to-kiln-temperature-ranges-for-pottery). Again, this calls for a *great deal of energy*, so you'd pay far more for the cost of heating and the carbonate than for $\ce{KOH}$ alone. Also, at 1200 °C, the $\ce{KOH}$ *evaporates*, so it would have to be condensed on a cooler surface. It might also shorten the life of the kiln. On second thought, this sounds like a project that would be described in Derek Lowe's blog, [*Things I Won’t Work With*](https://blogs.sciencemag.org/pipeline?s=things%20I%20won%27t%20work%20with).

@Poutnik suggests a displacement reaction with $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$, which would be far easier, but leaves the user to purify his product from remaining calcium -- calcium soaps tend to be insoluble.

In any case, $\ce{KOH}$ is **very** caustic: ["CAUSES SERIOUS EYE DAMAGE. CAUSES SEVERE SKIN BURNS..."](https://www.essentialdepot.com/msds/KOH_MSDS.pdf) **Use caution!**

Comment: What other potassium salts are generally available??

Comment: @Jaredbrandt K2CO3 is often available as well.// Just for curiosity - it is  largely used in Dutch processing of cocoa ( cocoa gets from light brown to dark brown by the process ) to produce chocolate from inferior cocoa beans, enhancing cocoa flavour and removing acidity.

Comment: Potassium bicarbonate is used in agriculture as a fungicide, and as a soil conditioner to control acidity. It is also used in dry powder fire extinguishers, and as an alternative to sodium bicarbonate (baking soda) in cooking by people on a low-sodium diet. Depending how pure you need it, you should be able to find a source for it somewhere.

Comment: I am curious, how would you easily convert K2CO3 to KOH by heating at home , assuming you cannot afford even KOH shipping. The medieval way M2CO3 + Ca(OH)2(from bricklayers) -> CaCO3 + 2 MOH seems to be much easier.

Comment: @Poutnik, "*a great deal of energy*" was stated. Perhaps a pottery kiln? Decomposition temp ~1200 °C, which can be reached in a kiln. Amending answer for that.Admittedly, *not* easy to do.

Comment: Controlling of bubbling melted carbonate ( m.p < 900 Deg C) seems more difficult than checking/precipitating of residual calcium by extra carbonate. Glowing foam could easily cause fire.